# post a message in facebook using appid and app secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i  post a message "Hello" in my facebook page using app id and app secret, when my facebook is in online, Message get posted sucessfully

but now my problem is i want to post a same messsage when facebook is in offline

and also it should work in all browswers

Answer (score 0):

That´s not possible, you can´t just use username/password. If you want to post something on your Page while being offline you have to authorize an App with the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permission and use a Page Token. This would be the API call: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish

About Page Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: i post a message in my page when iam in online it is working in google chrome but it is not working in other browsers why?

Comment: that´s a user support question, we only concentrate on programming questions on stackoverflow

Comment: The cleanest (and simplest way without crude workarounds) is what @luschn suggested. It's a matter of 2mins to get an eternal page access token. And you're done.

Comment: ok thanks luschn and Tobi for quick response                                                            Thanks Have a nice day